# Pass arraycollection to PHP

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I try to pass an Arraycollection to php.
To do that, I use this function:

```
  public function arrayCollectionToString( myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection ):String  
    {  
        var collStr:String = new String();  
        for each( var obj:Object in myArrayCollection )  
        {  
            collStr += "[";  
            var i:int=0;
            for each( var obj2:Object in obj )  
            {  i++;

                if(i==1){
                    collStr += obj2.toString();  

                }else{
                    collStr +=", "+ obj2.toString();  

                }
            }  
            collStr += "]";  
        }  
        return collStr;  
    }
```

This function transform arraycollection in string, but how to know in witch order key appear ? 
Or if it's not possible, how transmit keyname to php and split the string in php script to transform string into array?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you transforming your ArrayCollection into a String? Which remoting method are you using?

Comment: I transform arraycollection into string because I use httpservice and post method to communicate with php.

Answer (score 3):

The best method to exchange data between flash app and php script is using json. You can see it here for more detail: http://digitalmemo.neobie.net/2009/10/22/passing-object-from-flash-as3-to-php/ and here http://digitalmemo.neobie.net/2009/10/22/passing-object-from-flash-as3-to-php/. You convert your flash native array to json using as3corelib (http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) and handle json by json_decode() method in php.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with including array ok key in my function:

```
var keys:Array = ["idLien", "codeRDV", "nomRDV"];


var sGrpRDV:String = new ArrayFunction().arrayCollectionToString2(DP_GRP_RDV_D,keys); 


  public function arrayCollectionToString2( myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection, myOrderKey:Array ):String  
    {  
        var collStr:String = new String();  
        for each( var obj:Object in myArrayCollection )  
        {  
            collStr += "[";  
            var i:int=0;
            for each (var k:String in myOrderKey)
            {
                i++;
                if(i==1){
                    collStr += obj[k];  

                }else{
                    collStr +=", "+ obj[k];  

                }
            }

            collStr += "]";  
        }  
        return collStr;  
    }
```